# I save my video in blender, there is a scene when it snows, but it is not in the saved video

Tags: rendering, materials

I use blender 4.0 version. I made snowing scene, it works when I play it in blender, but when I render it there isn't any snow.

Comment: Hello, maybe show some screenshots, are you sure that the particle system is enabled for render?

Comment: Hello, Diana, welcome to BSE. There's not enough information here for us to make a sensible guess about what's wrong. The best way would be to make a simple version, (Perhaps the non-rendering snow all by itself), and share that on https://blend-exchange.com/, following the instructions there, and pasting the generated link into your  post.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.